# Killing screen session and starting a new one, cron

Tags: cron, gnu-screen

I have a screen session I run with a couple windows going on it that are running a couple applications that run a console in the terminal window (thus why I run them in screen).

I would like to be killing all the windows and then adding two new ones back that essentially just re-run the command to start the program up again.

Since this may be a little confusing here is what I would do if I was just trying to do this manually on the command line:

```
$ screen -x programs

$ (Hit Control-a + \ )

$ (Hit Control-a + c)

$ program1 args0 args1 #running first program again

$ (Hit Control-a + c)

$ program2 args0 args1 #running second program
```

Technically I don't even need to kill the existing windows, just stop the interactive window running. Normally I do this when in the window I just hit CTRL-D and the program stops running. Then I just run the program again.

I know there are commands so that I can attach to the existing screen session by name, I just have no idea how I could use that to send the equivalent of CTRL+D and then send another command to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to quit your screen session.

`screen -dr your_session_name -X quit`

Note:

Different Linux/Unix systems have different ways to handle long running processes. If your system controls processes using `systemd`, and the its version is above `230`, try to read the latest manual of systemd.